# How can map a rectf on a rotated bitmap

Tags: java, android, matrix

How can i map a RectF bounding box on android if the bitmap is (or not) rotated ?

I already have the RectF on the left image, need to map its coordinates to the right image.

[Awesome paint description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5H8h.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Android Matrix has a [mapPoints](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix#mapRect(android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.RectF)) method of RectF, it depends on how exactly you have rotated the bitmap, if you have drawn it with [drawBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint)) with a Matrix you can just re-use that Matrix.

You can [getMatix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getMatrix()) on a View as getting the Matrix from the Canvas is deprecated.